# How to print JSON a date in correct format returned from a REST API?

Tags: mysql, json, spring-mvc

I have written a REST API which gets data from a database. I have a column in my table which stores a date. I am using timestamp format to store the date.

My issue is when I am fetching the data, I'm not able to display the date in the proper format. I am getting `1420655400000` instead of `2015-01-08 00:00:00`.

Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getEstimation" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
public   List<Estimation1> getEstimation(ModelAndView model) throws IOException{

    List<Estimation1> estdetail;
    estdetail= estimation.getEstimationbyId(5);

    return estdetail;

}
```

Implementation of `getEstimationId(double)`:

```
@Override
    public List<Estimation1> getEstimationbyId(double id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);  
     String sql = "SELECT * FROM estimation where est_id=" +id;
     List<Estimation1> estimdetails= jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new RowMapper<Estimation1>()

           {
                @Override
                public Estimation1 mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException

                {
                    Estimation1 aContact = new Estimation1();
                    aContact.setDate(rs.getTimestamp("est_date"));

                    aContact.setEst_contactperson(rs.getString("est_contact_person"));
                    aContact.setEst_customer(rs.getString("est_customer"));
                    aContact.setEst_revision(rs.getInt("est_revision"));
                    aContact.setEst_prjt(rs.getString("est_project"));
                    aContact.setEst_status(rs.getString("est_status"));

                    return aContact;
                }
            });
    return estimdetails;
}
```

Here is the data which I am getting from the database after execution:

```
[{"date":1420655400000,"est_prjt":"project1","est_revision":0,"est_customer":null,"est_contactperson":"robert","est_status":null,"est_id":0.0,"ec":null}]**
```

What changes should I make to print the date in the proper format?

Comment: What are the property for the values in aContact?

Comment: @KayNelson property..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give a hint to the Jackson's object mapper of the format in which you want your dates to be deserialized. Following should work out for you

```
 @JsonFormat(shape= JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
 private Timestamp date;
```